# Flash - Loader errors in Firefox

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, firefox, actionscript, loader

I'm writing an application which pulls up to several dozen images from a server using Loader objects. It works fine in all browsers except Firefox, where I'm finding that, with over 6 or so connections, some simply never load - and I cease to get progress events (and can detect no errors/error events)

I extended the Loader class so that it will kill and reopen the transfer if it takes longer than ten seconds, but this temporary hack has created a new problem, in that when there are quite a few connections open, many of them will load 90-odd percent of the image, get killed for exceeding the time limit, open again, load 90-odd percent etc...until the traffic is low enough for it to actually complete. This means I'm getting transfers of many times the amount of data that is actually being requested!

It doesn't happen in any other browser (I was anticipating IE errors, so for Firefox to be the anomaly was unexpected!), I can write a class to manage Loaders, but wondered if anyone else had seen this problem?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try to limit number of concurrent connections.
Instead of loading all assets at once (then FP or browser manages the connections) try to build a queue.

Building a simple queue is fairly easy - just create an array of URLs and shift or pop a value every time loader has finished loading previous asset.
You might use an existing loader manager like [LoaderMax](http://www.greensock.com/loadermax/) or [BulkLoader](https://github.com/arthur-debert/BulkLoader) - they allow to create a queue, limit number of connections and are fairly robust. LoaderMax is my favourite.

Comment: Yeah this is what I think I'll have to do, but it's strange how this problem is only in FF, every other browser manages without any problem.

Comment: Gave you the answer because those managers are really useful, think we can fix the hassle with server-side management.